# I'm gonna change a plane in The US, do I need an ESTA?

Tags: usa, visas, esta, swedish-citizens

I'm flying from Costa-Rica to Newark and then to Stockholm. I'm a Swedish citizen.

ESTA = Electronic System for Travel Authorization.

Do I need one? This is what I'm refering to:
https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/

Comment: possible dublicate: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1538/flying-uk-to-canada-via-usa-do-i-need-to-apply-for-esta

Comment: indeed duplicate